# Bootstrap selectpicker - how to add opt group dinamically

Tags: html, jquery, each, bootstrap-selectpicker, optgroup

I have an array and I need to create a select picker with outgroup.

I try using jQuery with this code:

```
$.each(array, function(subindex, value) {
   if (subindex == 0){
    $('#select_template').append('<optgroup label="Camping">');
   }

$('#select_template').append(
                                           $('<option />')
                                          .text('Frontpage')
                                          .val(j)
                                          .attr('coll_index', index)
                                          .attr('page_index', subindex)
                                          .attr('style', 'font-style: italic;')
                                          .attr('custom_page', 'true')
                                         
                                      ); c++;

if (subindex == value.length - 1){
    $('#select_template').append('</optgroup>');
   }

});
```

but what I get is:

```
<select>
<optgroup label="Camping"></optgroup>
<option value="0" coll_index="0" page_index="0" style="font-style: italic;" custom_page="true">Frontpage</option>
<option value="1" coll_index="0" page_index="1" custom_page="false">Page 1</option>
<option value="2" coll_index="0" page_index="2" custom_page="false">Page 2</option>
</select>
```

How I can open and close optgroup dynamically using jQuery?

Comment: can you show your json structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the optgroup outside of the `$.each` loop e.g `$('#select_template').append('<optgroup label="Camping"></optgroup>');`.

To append to the options simply reference the optgroup in your append. Eg: `$('#select_template optgroup').append()`

**For example:**

```
  $('#select_template').append('<optgroup label="Camping"></optgroup>');

  $.each(array, function(subindex, value) {
    $('#select_template optgroup').append(
      $('<option />')
      .text('Frontpage')
      .val(j)
      .attr('coll_index', index)
      .attr('page_index', subindex)
      .attr('style', 'font-style: italic;')
      .attr('custom_page', 'true'));
  })
```

If you need to add multiple optgroup, then you'll need to supply the data for `array`

Heres a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/r2xpt3k6/